# How to write external function to call method invocation while compiling gleam code to JavaScript?

Tags: gleam

I am trying to write the Gleam JavaScript binding for basic DOM manipulation. I want to achieve following JavaScript functionality with gleam:

```
const div = document.createElement('div');

div.classList.add('className');
```

I am writing following external definition:

```
pub external type Document

pub external type HTMLElement

pub external fn create_elm(String) -> HTMLElement =
  "" "document.createElement"

// HOW TO WRITE FOLLOWING EXTERNAL DEFINITION
pub external fn add_class(HTMLElement, String) -> Nil =
  "" "$0.classList.add"
```

So, for `add_class` function, I want gleam to compile to JS such that first argument `HTMLElement` is used as a object and second argument `String` is passed to the some method of the `HTMLElement`. How to achieve this?

I could not find any documentation for this on gleam website. I thought something like the way Fable allows writing [external binding](https://fable.io/docs/communicate/js-from-fable.html#emit-when-f-is-not-enough) would be possible. However, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gleam doesn't have any functionality for working with OOP JavaScript so in this case I would use some JavaScript glue code.

```
// in src/app.gleam

pub type Document

pub type HTMLElement

@external(javascript, "./app_ffi.mjs", "createElement")
pub fn create_elm(kind: String) -> HTMLElement

@external(javascript, "./app_ffi.mjs", "addClass")
pub fn add_class(el: HTMLElement, class: String) -> Nil
```

```js
// in src/app_ffi.mjs

export function createElement(kind) {
  return document.createElement(kind)
}

export function addClass(element, string) {
  element.classList.add(string)
}
```